# Why do we care about the Bishop-de-Leeuw theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-distributions, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

The Bishop-de-Leeuw theorem says the following:

> Let $V$ be a topological vector space with $V^*$ separating and $C \subseteq V$ a non-empty,
>   compact, convex subset of $V$. Let $E$ be the set of extreme points of
>   $C$ and $X= \overline{E}$ (which is compact Hausdorff). For every $c
>  \in C$, there exists a Radon probability measure $\mu_c$ on the
>   compact Hausdorff space $X$ such that
>
> $$\forall \omega \in V^*: \omega(c) = \int_X \omega(x) \mu_c(dx)$$

I'm trying real hard to understand why this is a useful theorem or what it is trying to say. My notes mention it after proving the Krein-Milman theorem but does not use it in the sequel.

Why is this an important theorem? What is the theorem trying to say? From a probability theory point of view, this says

$$\forall c \in C: \exists \mu_c: \forall \omega \in V^*: \omega(c) = \mathbb{E}_{\mu_c}(\omega)$$

I.e. $\omega(c)$ can be seen as the expected value of the functional $\omega$ on $X$ w.r.t. the probability measure $\mu_c$.

Any insight in the applications of this theorem or why it is useful will be appreciated.

Comment: I've never seen this theorem before, but it looks a bit like an probability-space analogue of the Hahn-Banach theorem, which is a super important tool in functional analysis for representing bounded linear functionals. IMO, the biggest advantage of the H-B Theorem is that you can represent any bounded linear functional with a particularly nice structure.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the Hahn-Banach theorem. In fact, the proof of this theorem uses Hahn-Banach!

Comment: Cool! So perhaps the importance of this theorem is its use this as a representation theorem?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, so that's why I'm asking the question :)

Comment: @kimchilover Does he use Choquet's theorem to prove this? I'm aware of a classification of completely monotonuous functions via Krein-Milman, so maybe this is something analoguous.

Comment: I have deleted my comments.  Instead: your statement of the B-deL theorem is not the usual one, which has the representing measure supported on $E$, not on the closure of $E$.  What you state is a form of the Krein Milman theorem. The usual explanation of the difference is that there are compact convex sets $C$ (in a separable Hilbert space, say) for which $C=\overline E$, making the K-M representation vacuous in that case but the B-dL  one not.  Look at Phelps's book.